# How to add Webmethod in "Dynamic Data" on ASP.net with c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, dynamic-data, asp.net-dynamic-data

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string SaveFavourites(string id, bool check)
{
    //My Code here
}
```

This method is inside Dynamic Data folder(DynamicData/CustomePages/Products).
I just trigger ajax call to this method.

Unfortunatly its not working. Its return me "404 Not found"

Here my ajax CALL.

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "List.aspx/SaveFavourites",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            data: { "id": productID, "chkboxValue": chkboxValue },
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
```

Please Help at the earliest.

Comment: Is Name of your page List.aspx ?

Comment: Try by changing you webmethod  parameter as `SaveFavourites(string id, bool chkboxValue)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are putting incorrect url in jquery ajax call.

Is your page, where you have written jquery ajax call, is under DynamicData/CustomePages/Products? If yes then your url is correct otherwise you have to put correct url.

HINT : use relative path.